# How do I get the previous year in Razor syntax?

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, razor

I'm working on some templates to an ASP.NET MVC 3 application, only thing I have access to are the .cshtml template files. I really know nothing about .NET so I'm just trying to piece together somethings. In one of my templates i need to output the previous year.

I know I can get the current year with `@DateTime.Now.Year` but I can't find any info on how to get the previous year.

Comment: `DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year` ????

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).Year;
```

Answer (score 6):

Today, last year:

```
DateTime lastYear = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
```

Or just `@DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).year;`